# Excel: Add multiple tables into a single stacked column graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have been asked to make graphs of some evaluation forms, however I don't see how to make readable graphs with the data they gave me:

[image: the data they gave me.]

Every group has its own little table with data, the graph they want is an overview of how often each grade has been given.
For each group we want two stacked column charts, one per category. In which each part of the stack is the amount each grade is given. Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

(though ignore the line), but then with two columns per group.

Eventually more groups will be added and they have to be added to the charts as well, with minimum work.

I'm working in excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to restructure your data a bit in order to generate a chart of the type you want (skip to the end to see the chart!)

Put all your data into one table, with these headings:

```
- Group (A-E or however many groups you have)
- Grade (1-10)
- Frequency (number of students with that grade in that group)
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

Now, click select any cell in this table and on the ribbon click **Insert**, then **PivotTable**.

In the grey popup box click and drag *Group* and *Grade* into **Rows**, and drag *Frequency* into **Values**. You should get something like this:

[image]

Now, click somewhere in your PivotTable and insert a chart You should get a chart like this, grouping first by the Group name, then showing the distribution of total students by grade.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it is not really what I was looking for. We want to compare the grades given for the trainer and the total. If I understand correctly with this method you'd only compare the grades given in a group for either total or trainer. We'd like to compare both.

Comment: Like this you mean? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDqzt.png You could just add a second frequency column for the trainer's scores.